# Launch ec2 instance with chef

Tags: chef-infra

I started working recently on chef. I want to launch ec2 instance in my aws account using chef.
I have chef workstation(windows), chef node(windows 2012 R2), and chef server.
I need information about this, can anyone suggest me?

Comment: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/aws

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches:

1) https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-aws
  This one uses gem "aws-sdk", this is most right way of doing provisioning in AWS cloud. In this case you must have in your ChefDK's Gemfile: "chef-provisioning-aws" gem

2) https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-fog
  This provisioning solution is based on "Fog" gem and in fact it is multi-cloud solution and supports many popular clouds. To use that you must have in your ChefDK's Gemfile: "chef-provisioning-fog" gem

Please, see the README, it has clear explanation, but the common steps are:

- Set credentials via ENV[] or create profile for AWS in home directory of user
- Call machine resource with right machine_options and driver

Here is an example, in your recipe/provider/library you can do:

```
ENV['AWS_REGION'] = 'eu-central-1'
ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'YOUR_KEY_HERE'
ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE'

require 'chef/provisioning/aws_driver'
with_driver 'aws::eu-central-1'

machine 'instance-1' do
  action :converge
  machine_options :machine_options => {REFER TO MACHINE OPTIONS}
end
```

Comment: Thank You Baurzhan Konurbayev, your solution helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're talking about. If you just mean how to set up a server as a client instance, use `knife bootstrap`. If you want to both create a new EC2 instance and then bootstrap it, use `knife ec2 server create`.

Comment: `knife ec2 server create –I ami-456b493a -S D:/Key/admin.pem –f t2.small -x ubuntu –G sg-5d8b2c17 -s subnet-9d51ddc6 -Z us-east-1a`
Is this correct? How to launch or create a instance using Chef DK?